# Dart Flutter DevTools "Debugger" Tab not showing up

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Hello I'm trying to debug some issues with my app using dart DevTools and I notice that the "debugger" tab is not available to me. Here is a screenshot of what I see in the web debugger:

[image]

I notice that this article says I should have the "debugger" tab in the web DevTools: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I notice I have the debugger when I use AndroidStudio but would like to have it in VisualStudio Code

Comment: are you running on debug mode?

Comment: @Mayb3Not I select "Start Debugging" to run the app

Comment: yes but sometimes it will still run in profile if not configure properly. You can check what you running on the first line when you run your debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour when running from VS Code, as the VS Code debugger is available instead. There are complications with having two debuggers attached to the same app at the same time (both debuggers expect to control breakpoints and resuming) so it's disabled.

If you really want to try it you could just edit the `hide=debugger` out of the address, but be aware things might not work correctly (at least until the debuggers are able to work together better to avoid this limitation).

Comment: You are totally right, I realized this a bit after making the post and forgot about it. Built in debugger is great.